Resolve DNS for short name of the Active Directory domain
In trying to configure a SQL Server container for Active Directory, [the instructions]
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-join-domain?view=sql-server-ver16#check-the-connection-to-a-domain-controller) and troubleshooting
state that:

Check that you can contact the domain controller by using both the short and the fully qualified names of the domain


DNS lookups on the domain name and NetBIOS name should return the same IP address

For example, my Active Directory domain mydomain.dev, should resolve using:
nslookup mydomain
In both my test and production environment this lookup doesn't work.
$ nslookup mydomain.dev
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   mydomain.dev
Address: 172.31.10.20

$ nslookup mydomain
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find mydomain: SERVFAIL

Where/how do I configure this short/NetBIOS name?
The DC is Windows Server 2022 and I have otherwise setup the DNS, AD etc.

The controller FQDN and short name is different than what you write. Domain:contoso.com, ping contoso.com = ip of DC, nslookup ipDC=FQDN, ex; dc.contoso.com, ping dc (short name) = same result as ping dc.contoso.com IF and only if DNS suffix is on your NIC

But to answer you, both nslookup will work on fqdn or shortname if dns suffix is configured

I don't quite understand your 1st comment @yagmoth555, but your 2nd cleared it all up  (If I mischaracterized something, it is because I am operating at the edge of my knowledge here in AD, apologies!)

Windows DNS can resolve short names. You can enable and populate the GlobalNames zone on the DNS server.
DNS suffix search order and hosts file client side solutions also work.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/set-dnsserverglobalnamezone

Created the GlobalNames lookup zone as per docs and it works. Better than the /etc/resolv.conf option since it works automatically with less individual config per server

Thanks to @yagmoth555 comment, I realised that my /etc/systemd/resolved.conf was wrong and I had repeated the error in test and production
It was
[Resolve]
DNS=172.31.10.20
Domains=mydomain.dev mydomain

but it should have been
[Resolve]
DNS=172.31.10.20
Domains=mydomain.dev dev

Resolution now works: nslookup mydomain
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   mydomain.dev
Address: 172.31.10.20

